# how to detect when a transmitter is turned off?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, nrf24l01+, wireless

Using the nrf24l01 wireless module I want to control a led with the sketch below.
The transmitter automatically sends data at intervals of one second continuously and when the receiver counter reaches 2, it turns on the LED at the desired time and then turns it off.
but what I want is when I turn off the power of the transmitter when 2 counts are detected from the transmitter, the led does not light up.

I want to turn the led on and off when I turn off the power of the transmitter after sending 2 signals from the transmitter.

Thank you for all the information you provide.

```
#include "nRF24L01.h" 
#include "RF24.h"
#include "SPI.h"
int ReceivedMessage[1] = {000}; //  NRF24L01 tarafından alınan değeri saklamak için kullanılır
RF24 radio(3, 4); //  NRF24L01 SPI pimleri. uno'daki Pin 8 ve 9
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE6E6E6E6E6E6; // 2 NRF24L01 arasındaki iletişim için aynı olması gerekir

int led = A7;

bool flag = false;
bool ledflag  = false;
unsigned long  previous1 = 0;
unsigned long  interval1 = 5000;

unsigned long  previous2 = 0;
unsigned long  interval2  = 2000;
int button1PushCounter = 0;


void setup () {


  radio.begin(); // NRF24L01'i başlatın

  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe); // NRF24L01'i almaya hazır hale getirin

  radio.startListening(); // Bilginin alınıp alınmadığını görmek için dinleyin

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);


}

void loop () {

  unsigned long currentmillis = millis();
  while (radio.available())
  {
    radio.read(ReceivedMessage, 1); // NRF24L01'den bilgileri okuyun

    if (ReceivedMessage [0] == 111) //  switch'e basıldığını gösterir
    {

      button1PushCounter++;
      Serial.println( button1PushCounter);
      delay(700);
    }

    if ( button1PushCounter == 2) {

      flag = true;
      previous1 =  currentmillis;

    }

    if ( flag ) {
      if (currentmillis - previous1 >= interval1  ) {

        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        ledflag  = true;
        previous2 =  currentmillis;
        flag = false;
        button1PushCounter = 0;
      }
    }

    if ( ledflag && (currentmillis - previous2 >= interval2  )) {
      digitalWrite(led,  LOW);
      ledflag  = false;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what problem are you seeing?

Comment: @ -jsotola when i turn off the power of the transmitter, the receiver does not light the led with the detecting data

Comment: it seems to me that you used a lot of words to ask `how to detect when a transmitter is turned off?`

Comment: This is what happens when the problem is not knowing the language

Comment: you already have the code ... just rearrange it a bit ... basically implement a watchdog timer ... when signal is received, store the value of millis ... if the difference between stored value and millis() is more than 1 second, then the signal did not arrive

Comment: I don't know how to do it with watchdog unfortunately

Comment: no, not a hardware watchdog timer ... just use software

Comment: I did as you said, but failed.It works when the power supply is on. It does not work when I turn off the power supply.

Comment: your code only runs if `while (radio.available())` ... i am guessing that radio.available() may be false when the transmitter is turned off

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't run it according to this library.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the for loop

Answer (score 1):

I found solution as below:-

```
if ( button1PushCounter == 3 ) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(i);
    a = HIGH;
  }
}

if ( a == HIGH ) {

  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(led,  LOW);
  a = LOW;
  button1PushCounter = 0;
}
```